# JSON encode an array with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json, encoding

I'm trying to figure out how to encode the following:

```
$data[] = '';
//check if real player
if($steam_name != null){
    $data['valid'] = true;
    $data['url'] = "http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?key=key&vanityurl=$steam_name";
    echo json_encode($data, file_get_contents($data->url));
}else{
    $data['valid'] = false;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

I understand how to get the data, but it seems to not be sending through.

Thanks!

My attempt as per answer below. This does not work:

```
$data[] = '';
//check if real player
if($steam_name != null){
    $data['valid'] = true;
    $url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?';
    $params = [
       'key' => 'key',
       'vanityurl' => $steam_name,
    ];

    $data['url'] = $url . http_build_query($params); 
    echo json_encode($data);

}else{
    $data['valid'] = false;
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: George, this is JS, I need to know how it passes through as well, considering it's more than what expected.. thx bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using [http_build_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to accomplish that.

```
$url = 'http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/ResolveVanityURL/v0001/?';
$params = [
   'key' => 'abc123',
   'vanityurl' => $steam_name,
];

$data['url'] = $url . http_build_query($params);
```

That will handle the proper encoding for the parameters.

Additionally, `$data` is an array here, you can't call it like an object in your `file_get_contents` call. I'm surprised you aren't getting an exception. Also, [json_encode doesn't accept parameters like that](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Try this:

```
// Store the API response in your data array
$data['response'] = file_get_contents($data['url']);

// Return it so you can use it
return json_encode($data);
```

If the response is JSON, you can decode it:

```
$data['response'] = json_decode(file_get_contents($data['url']));
```

Comment: Thanks! So would my encode look like just 'json_encode($data);'?

Comment: and what is baseurl?

Comment: Sorry, baseUrl was something I had started to type then changed it to just url.

Comment: You're the man. Thank you for this. Sorry if I sounded rude, I get frustrated with people when they answer something but don't explain it exactly. Thanks again!

Comment: No offense taken. I have a day job ;)